# Google Cloud SDK to create a Cloud Run Job

Tags: java, sdk, jobs, google-cloud-run

We are trying to create a Cloud Run job programmatically using the Java SDK. So far we have been able to use classes in the `com.google.cloud.run.v2` to create a service, doing something like this:

```java
Container container = Container.newBuilder().setImage(image).build();

try (ServicesClient servicesClient = ServicesClient.create()) {

    log.debug("Creating service");

    CreateServiceRequest request =
        CreateServiceRequest.newBuilder()
            .setParent(LocationName.of(projectId, location).toString())
            .setService(Service.newBuilder().
                setTemplate(RevisionTemplate.newBuilder().addContainers(container)).
                                build())
            .setServiceId("hello")
            .build();
    Service response = servicesClient.createServiceAsync(request).get();
}
```

We would like to know if there is a similar Java API that allows us to create Cloud Run jobs instead of services.

Comment: Google provides 2 parallel sets of libraries. The original API Client Libraries that are machine-generated and available for all Google services. The Cloud Client Libraries that are (still?) hand-written and only available for Google Cloud services. The Cloud Client Libraries can lag in providing functionality that matches the underlying service. The API client libraries are generally (!) perfect replicas of the underlying service.

Comment: I think the [Java Cloud Client Library for Cloud Run](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/java-run) doesn't yet support Jobs (see [Overview](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-run/latest/overview)). The [Java API Client Library for Cloud Run](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-run/v2/2.0.0) includes [`GoogleCloudRunV2Job`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-run/latest/com/google/api/services/run/v2/model/GoogleCloudRunV2Job.html)

Comment: Google [Client libraries explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained)

Comment: You may want to bug Google to maintain the Cloud Client Library.

Comment: Hello DazWilkin and thanks for the input, maybe you want to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides 2 parallel sets of libraries. See Google [Client libraries explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

The original API Client Libraries that are machine-generated and available for all Google services. The API client libraries are generally (!) perfect replicas of the underlying service.

The Cloud Client Libraries that are (still?) hand-written and only available for Google Cloud services. The Cloud Client Libraries can lag in providing functionality that matches the underlying service.

I think the [Java Cloud Client Library for Cloud Run](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/java-run) doesn't yet support Jobs (see [Overview](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-run/latest/overview)).

The [Java API Client Library for Cloud Run](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-run/v2/2.0.0) includes [`GoogleCloudRunV2Job`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-run/latest/com/google/api/services/run/v2/model/GoogleCloudRunV2Job.html).