# How can we update only traffic on revisions via Google Run java SDK?

Tags: java, google-cloud-run

We tried to use UpdateServiceRequest in Google Cloud Run Java SDK to update traffic percentages among existing revisions of a Google Cloud Run Service. But the api call always tries to create new revision.
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.run.v2#google.cloud.run.v2.UpdateServiceRequest
Using CLI tool you can update traffic among revisions using following command
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services/update-traffic
Our goal is to achieve same via Google Run Java SDK.

Comment: Can you refer to this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586487)